# Angular 7, Asp.net web api, assigning roles to users

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-web-api, dropdown, angular7

I have an ASP.NET Web API with Angular 7 material design client side. I want to assign a role to a current user,
I have a user that I'm trying to assign a role to. I've got the .Net part working, but I can not figure out how to implement it on the angular side. I'm not sure if I'm getting the select dropdown correctly implemented. 
In my console.log(), the role is coming up as 'undefined'. Any help is appreciated.

The below is the current code.

> ASP.NET Web API

```
     [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Role(Roles role)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            var assignRole = await _contextFile.AddRoles(role.Email, role.UserRoles);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

> Angular 7
>
> > Service

```
userRole(email: string, role: string){
  return this.http.post(this.Url +  {email, role});
}

populateDropdownRoles(){
  return this.http.get(this.roleUrl);
}
```

> > .ts file

```
assignRole() {
 this.roleService.userRole(this.user.email, this.role);
}
dropdownRole() {
this.roleService.populateDropdownRoles();
}
```

> .html file

```
<form (ngSubmit)="assignRole()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Email"
      name="email"
      value="{{ user.email}}"  
    />
  </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Role">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" name ="rolename" [(ngModel)]="role.rolename" value="{{role.rolename}}">
        {{role.rolename}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
    <button
      mat-raised-button
      type="submit"
    >
      Assign
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `<mat-select>` should contain the `[(ngModel)] ` directive not the `<mat-option>`.  The `[(ngModel)]` should bind to a value in the component class.

Comment: `<mat-select placeholder="Role" [(ngModel)]="rolename">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" name ="rolename"  value="{{role.rolename}}">
        {{role.rolename}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>`

Comment: Something like the above?

Comment: yes, then declare `rolename` in your component class

Comment: In the docs, you can look at the code for the third example. https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: I wish I can say that it has fixed my problem. But I'm still getting the 'undefined' error on my browser. I have declared `rolename` in the component, and used `ngModel` in the `mat-select`

Comment: did you declare `rolename` in your component and change `assignRole()` to refer to the new var declaration?

Comment: So something like this? `assignRole() { this.roleService.userRole(this.user.email, this.roleName) }`
If so, I have done that. That didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just mocked this up really quickly which is working.  You may have to modify some of the variable names.

- Moved `[(ngModel)]` and `name` to the `<mat-select>` element.
- Declared the variable that is being bound to `[(ngModel)]` inside component class.
- Printed out selected value in `assignRole()` method.

NOTE: This is assuming your are successfully receiving role values back from your API.  I added a mock roles array inside the component class.

---

#### component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-roles-form',
  templateUrl: './roles-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roles-form.component.css']
})
export class RolesFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public roles = [{ rolename: 'user' }, { rolename: 'admin' }];
  public selectedRole: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  assignRole() {
    console.log('selectedRole: ', this.selectedRole);
  }

}
```

#### component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="assignRole()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Role" [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" name="selectedRole">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" value="{{role.rolename}}">
        {{role.rolename}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button type="submit">
    Assign
  </button>
</form>
```

---

### DOCS

> https://stackblitz.com/angular/gokjjqynqvo?file=main.ts
>
> https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: Jason you beautiful wizard. Thank you very much for taking the time to assist a noob like myself!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed: The name of you model in the controller is role and it is a string according to the parameters received in the service method, so you should use [(ngModel)]="role" and also I think you should put it at the mat-select tag not the mat-option. So your html should look something like this.

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="role"  name ="role"  placeholder="Role">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" value="{{role.rolename}}">
    {{role.rolename}}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

PS: I would suggest you change the name of the model to roleName. like this.roleName and [(ngModel)]="roleName" name ="roleName" it would be less confusing for you.
[You could check the example here](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Comment: Hi Frantz, unfortunately, that didn't do it for me. I tried what you've suggested and I did not get the desired result. I'm still getting `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You have the `ngModel` wrong, `ngModel` goes on the control, not the options.

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="role" name ="rolename" placeholder="Role">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.rolename">
    {{role.rolename}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

After that you need to check on the `.Net` part the structure of the class `Role` because, if my memory is not failing, the `UserRoles` property is a list of selected roles, if that is correct you need to send an array of roles, not just one role.

Comment: Hi Omar, thank you for your feed back. What would the structure in the component look like? Should I declare the role as `role: = []`? Sorry for the basic questions. I'm still learning.

Comment: If is correct that the `Role` class on .Net is expecting a list of roles, yeah, it's something like that, but, that raises the problem of how to bind the selected value, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can you provide the .Net `Role` class in your question?

Comment: Yes. So it would be a list of roles. I'll be waiting for your reply! Thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean the model? The model is set as `public string Role {get;set;}`

Comment: No, in your .Net endpoint you receive a parameter, the Type is `Roles` (sorry, my mistake of putting it singular instead of plural), for what I can see it contains an email and a list of roles, what I want is that class whole structure (properties and types)